# Managing clickable images (with position) in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, imagemap

how do I make an image I'm displaying clickable such that it returns the position in the image where the click occurred? or can I define hot spots on an image that have callbacks? or some other idea I haven't even considered? I want to display a map and have something happen when, for instance, a specific city is clicked on.

Comment: there is no built-in solution: you need a `GestureDetector` and some math since most likely your image will be resized on the screen

Comment: i may create use stack, and on top of it i will add some buttons, or gird. everything should be inside `SizedBox>layoutbuilder>stack`. can you share that image?

Comment: those are both useful ideas, thanks! the image is just a standard map, nothing too exciting (but it's not mine to share)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  OverlayEntry _addSpot(Offset pos) {
    return OverlayEntry(
      maintainState: true,
      builder: (context) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: pos.dy - 10,
              left: pos.dx - 10,
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Container(
                  width: 10,
                  height: 10,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCard(int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (details) {
        Overlay.of(context).insert(_addSpot(details.globalPosition));
      },
      child: //your image
    );
  }
```